# How to NACK Google Cloud PubSub message through their REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

The closest thing to NACK a message seems to be to set [`modifyAckDeadline`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/modifyAckDeadline) to 0.

There they mention that:

> This method is useful ... to make the message available for redelivery if the processing was interrupted.

Is this really the default way to do it (it seems hackish a bit), or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling modifyAckDeadline with a value of 0 is exactly the way to NACK a message. That is what the client libraries do as well, e.g., [Java](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/fe89bd354c219c64c458724d4b5e78e3828c8845/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/MessageDispatcher.java#L465-L470). This essentially tells Pub/Sub that the client wants no more time to ack the message, which means it becomes a candidate for redelivery.